# How to make JOIN in after where clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq To Entity.
I have this rows:

```
     var data= from ir in Context.InspectionReview
               from so in Context.SiteObjects
               where ir.SiteId == r.SiteId
               where so.SiteId == r.SiteId && so.SiteRegionId == r.Id
```

How can I make `inner join` - `ir` on `so` after where clause?

Comment: Why do you think you should need to join after the where clause, if you could do it what difference would you expect it to make to joining before the where clause

Comment: it more effective,doesn't it?

Comment: @Michael nope, no difference. the expression you wrote at last complied to underling provider (T-SQL,...). LINQ consider all of them, analyse and compile them ;)